# How to configure MySQL exporter Helm chart for multiple targets (remote & local)?

Tags: prometheus, kubernetes-helm, mysql

I have been trying for a few days to set up a multi-target MySQL exporter (MSE) deployed with Helm inside a k8s cluster. The chart that I am using is the https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/prometheus-community/prometheus-mysql-exporter/2.2.0 (latest as of today).
It works when I try to connect directly to the primary DB without using the multi-target config in `values.yaml/serviceMonitor` : I can see the data in my grafana.

I see in the documentation that I can specify multiple targets for my MSE and have filled the `values.yaml` accordingly (see `values.yaml` below). I have enabled the multi-target and have specified that the password is not the same for both targets.
My targets are both MariaDB databases : one is external to the cluster (accessible by IPv4) and the other one is an helm-deployed MariaDB inside the cluster.

Some attention points :

- exporter user is present on both the primary and the replica, with permission access from everywhere (%) for testing purposes.
- `my.cnf` is deployed as a secret in the cluster and recovered successfully by the mysql-exporter pod in `/etc/cnf/my.cnf` (see file below)

What I get when I do `helm upgrade` is the following, from my pod's logs :
`caller=exporter.go:152 level=error msg="Error pinging mysqld" err="dial tcp [::1]:3306: connect: connection refused"`

Questions :

- Is it a stable feature ?
- Is the documentation accurate when it says to not use [client] but instead [client.name] ?
- Can it work if one of both databases connection is not successful ?
- How to make it work ?

**my.cnf**

```
[client]
user=NOT_USED
password=NOT_USED
[client.mariadb-staging]
user=exporter
password=XXXXXXXXX
[client.replica-1]
user=exporter
password=XXXXXXXXXX
```

**values.yaml**

```
## Default values for prometheus-mysql-exporter.
## This is a YAML-formatted file.
## Declare variables to be passed into your templates.

## namespaceOverride overrides the namespace which the resources will be deployed in
namespaceOverride: ""

## override release name
fullnameOverride: ""

replicaCount: 1

image:
  registry: quay.io
  repository: prometheus/mysqld-exporter
  ## if not set charts appVersion var is used
  tag: ""
  pullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"

# imagePullSecrets:
# - name: secret-name
imagePullSecrets: []

service:
  labels: {}
  annotations: {}
  name: mysql-exporter
  type: ClusterIP
  externalPort: 9104
  internalPort: 9104

serviceMonitor:
  # enabled should be set to true to enable prometheus-operator discovery of this service
  enabled: true
  # interval is the interval at which metrics should be scraped
  interval: 30s
  # scrapeTimeout is the timeout after which the scrape is ended
  scrapeTimeout: 10s
  namespace: monitoring
  # additionalLabels is the set of additional labels to add to the ServiceMonitor
  additionalLabels: {}
  jobLabel: ""
  targetLabels: []
  podTargetLabels: []
  metricRelabelings: []
  # Set relabel_configs as per https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config
  relabelings: []
  # Enable multi target scraping.
      # target connection information with name (required), endpoint (required) and port (optionnal)
      # if sharedSecret is not enabled the name must match an entry client.{{ name }} existing in the secret
  multipleTarget:
    enabled: true
    targets:
      - name: mariadb-staging
        endpoint: xx.xxx.xxx.32
        port: 3306
      - name: replica-1
        endpoint: metabase-mariadb.database.svc.cluster.local
        port: 3306
    # Enable shared credentials for all targets
    sharedSecret:
      enabled: false
      name: ""

serviceAccount:
  # Specifies whether a ServiceAccount should be created
  create: false
  # The name of the ServiceAccount to use.
  # If not set and create is true, a name is generated using the fullname template
  name:
  annotations: {}

resources: {}
  # We usually recommend not to specify default resources and to leave this as a conscious
  # choice for the user. This also increases chances charts run on environments with little
  # resources, such as Minikube. If you do want to specify resources, uncomment the following
  # lines, adjust them as necessary, and remove the curly braces after 'resources:'.
  #limits:
  # cpu: 100m
  # memory: 128Mi
  #requests:
  # cpu: 100m
  # memory: 128Mi

nodeSelector: {}

tolerations: []

affinity: {}

podLabels: {}

# Extra Volume Mounts for the mysql exporter container
extraVolumeMounts: []
# - name: example
#   mountPath: /example

# Extra Volumes for the pod
extraVolumes: []
# - name: example
#   configMap:
#     name: example

podSecurityContext: {}
  # fsGroup: 65534

securityContext: {}
  # capabilities:
  #   drop:
  #   - ALL
  # readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
  # runAsNonRoot: true
  # runAsUser: 65534

annotations:
  prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
  prometheus.io/path: "/metrics"
  prometheus.io/port: "9104"

config: {}
  # Allow to set specifc options on the exporter
  # logLevel: info
  # logFormat: "logger:stderr"

collectors:
  # auto_increment.columns: false
  # binlog_size: false
  engine_innodb_status: true
  # engine_tokudb_status: false
  # global_status: true
  # global_variables: true
  # info_schema.clientstats: false
  # info_schema.innodb_metrics: false
  # info_schema.innodb_tablespaces: false
  # info_schema.innodb_cmp: false
  # info_schema.innodb_cmpmem: false
  # info_schema.processlist: false
  # info_schema.processlist.min_time: 0
  # info_schema.query_response_time: false
  # info_schema.tables: true
  # info_schema.tables.databases: '*'
  # info_schema.tablestats: false
  # info_schema.schemastats: false
  # info_schema.userstats: false
  # perf_schema.eventsstatements: false
  # perf_schema.eventsstatements.digest_text_limit: 120
  # perf_schema.eventsstatements.limit: false
  # perf_schema.eventsstatements.timelimit: 86400
  # perf_schema.eventswaits: false
  # perf_schema.file_events: false
  # perf_schema.file_instances: false
  # perf_schema.indexiowaits: false
  # perf_schema.tableiowaits: false
  # perf_schema.tablelocks: false
  # perf_schema.replication_group_member_stats: false
  slave_status: true
  # slave_hosts: false
  # heartbeat: false
  # heartbeat.database: heartbeat
  # heartbeat.table: heartbeat

# mysql connection params which build the my.cnf config
mysql:
  db: ""
  host: ""
  ## config my.cnf https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-options.html
  additionalConfig:
    - connect-timeout=5
    - debug
  pass: ""
  port: ""
  protocol: ""
  user: ""
  # secret with full config my.cnf
  existingConfigSecret:
    name: "config-mysql-exporter"
    key: "my.cnf"
  # secret only containing the password
  #existingSecret: "connection-string-mariadb"
  #existingPasswordSecret:
  #  name: ""
  #  key: ""
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to probe the exporter in order to get your metric, like this : `curl 'http//{IPADRESSE}:9104/probe?auth_module=client.{name}&target={ENDPOINT}:{PORT}'`